# Accessing the value of the JSON data in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, json.net

I am trying to retrieve the value of the JSON data and assign it to the JSON variable in the Angular like this:

```
$scope.bulkCreateRequest = function (jsonData) {
        var data = {
            "SERVICEREASON": jsonData.ServiceReason,
            "SITE": jsonData.Site,
            "FACILITY": jsonData.Location,
         };
}
```

When I debug the application though the jsonData has content, it says defined for SERVICEREASON,SITE,FACILITY like below in Local

[image]

[image]

I am not sure what I am missing here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`jsonData` seems to be an array, so `jsonData[0]["ServiceReason"]` should work, also first verify if its a string, if it is then you will have to first convert it to array of object like `jsonData = JSON.parse(jsonData)`

so final code might look like -

```
$scope.bulkCreateRequest = function (jsonData) {
    jsonData = JSON.parse(jsonData);
    var data = {
        "SERVICEREASON": jsonData[0]["ServiceReason"], // this will also work
        "SITE": jsonData[0].Site,
        "FACILITY": jsonData[0].Location,
    };
};
```